# How to make hashed passwords laravel 6

Tags: laravel, authentication, hash, passwords, user-registration

I have created a form where the admin can register accounts on the system. The problem is that the password is not hashed when the user is created on the admin side, and I think this is what stops the user from logging in on the system. Do you have any tips for me to make this work? I'm a total newbie at Laravel so.

I think the problem is in this code..

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|string|max:25|unique:users',
        'phone' => 'required|string|max:12|min:11|unique:users',
        'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        'membership_term' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'mode_of_payment' => 'required|string',
    ]);

    $user = new User;
    $user->firstname = $request->input('firstname');
    $user->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
    $user->username = $request->input('username');
    $user->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $user->address = $request->input('address');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->membership_term = $request->input('membership_term');
    $user->mode_of_payment = $request->input('mode_of_payment');
    $user->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'Data Updated.')->with('users', $user);
}
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that when using the 'confirmed' validation rule to include a 'password_confirmation' field as well to satisfy the validation. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-confirmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; 

$user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel helper function `bcrypt()`

```php
$user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-bcrypt